# Completion Block Issues

Tags: ios, swift

Okay so I have a potential problem that I need help/advice on. I have two functions that do the job of pulling keys from my database and then passing those keys to another function which ultimately grabs all the data.

This is the first function

```
static func showEvent(for currentLocation: CLLocation,completion: @escaping ([Event]) -> Void) {
    //getting firebase root directory
    var currentEvents = [Event]()
    var geoFireRef: DatabaseReference?
    var geoFire:GeoFire?
    geoFireRef = Database.database().reference().child("eventsbylocation")
     geoFire = GeoFire(firebaseRef: geoFireRef)
    let circleQuery = geoFire?.query(at: currentLocation, withRadius: 10.0)
    circleQuery?.observe(.keyEntered, with: { (key: String!, location: CLLocation!) in
        print("Key '\(key)' entered the search area and is at location '\(location)'")
        EventService.show(forEventKey: key, completion: { (event) in
            currentEvents.append(event!)
            completion(currentEvents)
        })
    })

}
```

This function uses the EventService.show function to ultimately grab the data like mentioned before.

```
 static func show(forEventKey eventKey: String, completion: @escaping (Event?) -> Void) {
        // print(eventKey)
        let ref = Database.database().reference().child("events").child(eventKey)
         print(eventKey)
        //pull everything
        ref.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, andPreviousSiblingKeyWith: { (snapshot,eventKey) in
            //print(snapshot.value ?? "")
            guard let event = Event(snapshot: snapshot) else {
                return completion(nil)
            }
           completion(event)
        })
    }
```

When both of these functions are done it returns back to my main function with the array of events to help populate my collectionView.

This is that function

```
@objc func grabUserLoc(){
    LocationService.getUserLocation { (location) in
        guard let currentLocation = location else {
            return
        }
        PostService.showEvent(for: currentLocation, completion: { (events) in
            self.allEvents = events
            print("Event count in PostService Closure:\(self.allEvents.count)")
            self.dynamoCollectionView.reloadData()
        }
        )
        print("Latitude: \(currentLocation.coordinate.latitude)")
        print("Longitude: \(currentLocation.coordinate.longitude)")
    }

}
```

Now upon tracing the stack I see that reloadData is called multiple times. Is there any way that I can go about fixing these functions to actually do the completion block when all the data is pulled. So that reloadData is called only once not every single time an instance of an event comes back?

I hope my question makes sense
DispatchGroups were brought to my attention could anyone maybe show me an implementation of an answer

Comment: Use a dispatchgroup, heres an example for swift 3 but I dont think anything has changed http://jordansmith.io/dispatch-groups-in-swift-3/

Comment: maybe an example of an answer?

Comment: maybe an example of an answer? @SeanLintern88

Answer (score 0):

Taken from the article in my comment:

```
let dispatchGroup = DispatchGroup()

dispatchGroup.enter()
longRunningFunction { dispatchGroup.leave() }

dispatchGroup.enter()
longRunningFunctionTwo { dispatchGroup.leave() }

dispatchGroup.notify(queue: .main) {
    print("Both functions complete ")
}
```

You create a group, in each Async activity you enter the group, when that Async activity finishes you leave the group, when the dispatch group leaves as many things as it enters it will call the notify.

EDIT:

So in your case you can either pass the group to the funcs, to leave when they are done or have each func have an optional completion which then is called back to your original to leave the group.

Comment: well I meant an answer in relation to my function

Comment: Um okay I just wanted an applicable example not a copy and paste from a site